# execute tcl commands as soon as signal has some value in ncsim

Tags: tcl, modelsim, cadence

As a modelsim user I am used to write something like the following lines in my do-file.

```
when -label supersignal {supersignal == '1'} {
   stop ;
   puts "blah"
   do_something
}

run -all
```

That runs the simulation in modelsim and as soon as my VHDL-Signal `supersignal` has the value '1' the block starting with `stop;` will be executed.

Is there a similar tcl command for (cadence) ncsim? I am looking for a command I can use within my dofile when calling `ncsim -input dofile.do`.
When I don't want to only stop the simulation, but also execute any tcl command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ncsim you can use

```
stop -create -object supersignal -silent -execute {
  puts "blah"
  do_something
}
```

That will not check for supersignal to be '1', but will trigger when there is any change to supersignal.
So if you want to check for the value explicitly you can create a condion first (see the `condition option` of stop or the `condition` command to create new conditions)